# Angular2 Upgrade tutorial code not bootstrapping

Tags: angular

I’m following along with the official [Angular2 upgrade guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#phonecat-upgrade-tutorial)

Currently the project is in phase 2.1 of the migration steps.  The tutorial says "the key is to do this piece by piece without breaking the application”, but I have broken the application.

The issue seems to be using the upgrade adapter to boot the app.  Following along with the section "Bootstrapping A Hybrid 1+2 PhoneCat", the app is failing to boot.
The symptoms are a blank screen and no errors in the console.

It's not clear where to put the bootstrap methods in the app/js/app.module.ts file.  The docs do not specify where the following code should go.  These are its exact words:

> We can then make an adapter by instantiating the class:
>
> ```
> const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
>  Now we can use that adapter to bootstrap our application as a hybrid.    Instead of calling angular.bootstrap, we must call
> ```
>
> upgradeAdapter.bootstrap, but the function arguments remain the same:
>   They are still the element that will become the root of the
>   application, and the names of the root Angular 1.x modules that we
>   want to include:
>
> ```
> upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['phonecatApp']);
> ```

Following some advice [here](http://www.codelord.net/2016/01/07/adding-the-first-angular-2-service-to-your-angular-1-app/), I tried this:

```
var upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
angular.element(document.body).ready(function() {
  upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['phonecatApp']);
});
```

Same result: blank screen, no console output.

What is the correct way to bootstrap this fusion state of the app?

The file in question is [here](https://github.com/timofeysie/angular-phonecat-upgrade/blob/master/app/js/app.module.ts).

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could try to load the module and then bootstrap the application.

Something like this:

- index.html

  ```
  <script>
    System.import('src/hello_world').then(function(src) {
      src.main();
    });
  </script>
  ```
- hello_world.ts

  ```
  import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
  import {Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';

  try {
    var upgrade = new UpgradeAdapter();

    (...)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  export function main() {
    try {
      upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp']);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
  ```

See this plunkr as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjghOFhFWuY8G1fVIEg?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks Thierry,  That works to bootstrap the app.  However, now I am having a problem with an unknown provider from the same file, the app.module.ts.  It's not finding the PhoneListCtrl, but I suppose that is a separate issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working contents of my main.ts file. The tutorial isn't very good about saying where the new lines should be added, it took me a bit to figure it out. The key was to add the providers and service factory before the bootstrap method.

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {Phone} from './core/phone/phone.service';

let upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();

upgradeAdapter.addProvider(HTTP_PROVIDERS);
upgradeAdapter.addProvider(Phone);
angular.module('core.phone').factory('phone', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Provider(Phone));

upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['phonecatApp']);
```

I have checked in the code to my repo on Github at: https://github.com/Rockncoder/phonecat. The commits are in the same order as the tutorial, so you can also see what changes I made following it.

Comment: Congrats on finishing the tutorial!  It took you about two days?  Your commit tagged Step 7 seems like a good place to pick up the trail.  But I cloned the repo, did:
    git reset --hard step-7
    npm start // to run the app after it carries our npm/bower install.
Then I got the following errors in main.js: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading 
Any idea what is the best spot to go to where there is a stable Angular1/Angular2 environment?

Comment: Two ideas off the top of my head. 1- It is necessary to do an npm install since the node_modules directory is not part of the repo. 2 - if you simply clone it to your own box, that will show the end results which are working.
Side note: I wasn't working solely on the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {UpgradeModule} from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule
    ],
})
export class AppModule{
    ngDoBootstrap(){}
}
```

Ensure the following entries exist in **systemjs.config.js** under angular bundles list

```
'@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
'@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
```

Refer to my [github repo](https://github.com/akbasu/PhoneCat-Angular2) for a working example. The commits were created after every step of the [PhoneCat Upgrade Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#phonecat-upgrade-tutorial).

Comment: Please don't just post a link, but add the substantial part for the answer to this post, for future reference.

Comment: Point noted. Posted code snippets from the working example that I posted above.